# $\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $\phi(x)<\epsilon$ for $x\in X$, then $\phi(x)\le \epsilon$ for $x\in\overline{X}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading a proof that if a sequence of functions from $M$ to $N$, where $N$ is complete, converges uniformly in $X$, then they converge uniformly in $\overline{X}$, and it uses this result:

$\phi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $\phi(x)<\epsilon$ for $x\in X$, then $\phi(x)\le \epsilon$ for $x\in\overline{X}$

which is proved like this:

the set of all points $x\in M$ such that $\phi(x)\le \epsilon$ is closed in M (WHY?) and contains $X$, which is the same as saying $\phi(x)\le \epsilon\forall x\in\overline{X}$

Comment: Part of being a good mathematician is to notice patterns. For example, the pattern of you putting the [set-theory] tag, and people removing it from the last three questions (and now four).

Comment: So ... is there a question here?

Comment: Are M,N $\subseteq \mathbb R$?Or are they arbitrary metric or topological spaces? That matters.

Comment: Continuous means the pre-image of closed sets are closed

Comment: @Frank Lu Dammit,beat me to it.........lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse image of a closed set under a continuous map is closed and since $\{y \in \mathbf{R}: y \leq \epsilon\}$ is closed, it follows that $\{x \in M: \phi(x) \leq \epsilon\}$ is closed.

Comment: where is the inverse image?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs The inverse image is $\phi^{-1}(S)$ = {$x\in M$| $\psi(x) \leq \epsilon $},which is a closed subset of M since it lies in a closed ball centered at x $\in$ M.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 "since it lies in a closed ball centered at x ∈ M." Which ball? Which x?

Comment: @Did A closed ball by definition chooses a random point x as the center where the other points are defined by d(x,y) $\leq \epsilon$. Check the definition of a metric!

Comment: Please learn to read: my question is not what is a ball but how your previous comment relates to anything. FYI, closed sets are not defined as those that "lie in a closed ball" hence the question in my comment still stands (except that now the best guess is that you simply do not know what you are saying).